# Tools for exporting Microsoft Access forms to HTML

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I have been tasked with converting a very large Microsoft Access application to ASP.NET. My client wants to keep the web layout somewhat similar to the Access layout. Are there any tools available to assist me in converting these forms into HTML? I would be happy with a tool that exports an HTML layout of textboxes and labels ignoring all databinding and code-behind logic.

I am using Access 2010 and have tried exporting the form as HTML but the result is completely unusable.

Comment: I am currently thinking about the same thing and I am wondering if using this tool and then taking the HTML files may work for and intial conversion. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/mig-index-095631.html

Answer (score 4):

The real problem is that you're really dealing with a different architecture. I mean it kind of like telling someone that you need some kind of transportation. A heavy duty truck and a lightweight small air plane are built with such very different desing goals.

Just the weight of the doors and even the door handle mechanisms on the truck will be 100% inappropriate for that small aircraft (and even just the weight and materials used will be all wrong).

The other problem of course is there are several "famous" and long used features of Access that give rise to the "look" and layout you are asking to replicate here. The first feature is of course continues forms. That means you place ONE row of controls on a form, but the data + controls REPEATS over and over. You don't have this simple UI in asp.net, and especially not a data bound seutp.

The beauty of such a system is forms like this can be created in Access in about a minute of your time:

[image]

The other way cool feature is how you "model" the one to many or relational data in Access. The common approach used here is what we call a sub form. A main form combined with sub form allows one to build + maintain parent to child relational data setups and again this occurs without any code. We talking about a form that looks like this:

[image]

(so in above, you see the equipment list - that is a sub form, a contineus form and as noted a "child" table of the parent. And such a desing takes zero code in Access). So I not sure some layout converter would help since the data binding of that sub form is 100% seperate from the main form, and mixing up the controls and layout during conversion would make MORE work and likly MORE of a mess that you have to un-tangle. In a nutsheel: this is very differnt!

Now to be fair, the above screen shots I have used are Access Web forms. You do realize for Access 2010 you have a web publishing ability. You can see in the following video of mine I switch to the half-way point and run the Access application 100% in a browser. There is no ActiveX or Silverlight required for this ability.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

The KEY SUGGESTING in the above is that this would enable to keep the same look + feel for the web based application since you would in fact be using Access to build the web form.

Unfortatnly, there is NOT an automated conversion of existing VBA forms to these new web forms for 2010.  I think it still better to re-layout the forms anyway. And as noted the database binding and seperation of UI from that of data processing code makes such a setup quite different anyway.

And without continues forms, and without sub forms, there not a one to one type of mapping that exists for asp.net forms anyway – but there *is* if you choose to use Access web forms.

At the end of the day, due to the web being so very different, I think it still makes sense to re-build the forms, but depending on the goals here, using the new web form publishing ability of Access would get you the same look and feel – including that of those "classic" use of continues forms, and also that of sub forms.